# validation in javascript not working in multiple if else statement?

Tags: javascript

Below is my javascript code - whenever agent radio  button is clicked it enters the 1st validation part and does not check the others:

```
function validate(form1) 
    {
        var agent1=document.getElementById('agent');
        var confirm=document.getElementById('confirm');
        var holding=document.getElementById('holding');
        var confirm=form1.confirm.value;
        var book_by=form1.bookby.value;
        var bkother=form1.bookbyother.value;
        var agntphn=form1.phone1.value;
        var gstnam=form1.guest_name.value;
        var gstphn=form1.guest_no.value;
        var adlts=form1.no_adults.value;
        var children=form1.no_child.value;
        var infants=form1.no_infants.value;
        var check_in=form1.checkin.value;
        var check_out=form1.checkout.value;
        var nfd1=form1.no_of_days.value;
        var rc=form1.roomtype.value;
        var rpd=form1.rp_day.value;
        var rpb=form1.extrarate.value;
        var tamt=form1.totalamount.value;
        var advamt=form1.advance_amount.value;

        if ((agent1.checked == true))
        {
            if(!(book_by || bkother))
            {
                alert('Choose the valid agent')
            }
            else if(agntphn =="")
            {
                alert('Enter the agent phone number')
            }
        }
        else if (gstnam=="") {
            alert("Enter a valid Name ");
            document.getElementById('guest_name').focus();
            return false;
            //errors[errors.length] = "Enter valid Name ";
        }
        else if (!ck_Mobileno.test(gstphn)) {
            alert("Enter a valid Mobile Number with 10 digits");
            document.getElementById('guest_no').focus();
            return false;
            //errors[errors.length] = "Enter valid mobileno ";
        }
        else if ((adlts=="") &&( children=="" )&&( infants=="")) {
            alert("Enter a valid No of persons");
            document.getElementById('no_adults').focus();
            return false;
            //errors[errors.length] = "Enter valid mobileno ";
        }
        else if (!(check_in)) {
            alert("Enter a valid Checkin Date");
            document.getElementById('checkin').focus();
            return false;
            //errors[errors.length] = "Enter valid mobileno ";
        }
        else if (!(check_out)) {
            alert("Enter a valid  check_out date");
            document.getElementById('checkout').focus();
            return false;
            //errors[errors.length] = "Enter valid mobileno ";
        }
        else if (!(nfd1)) {
            alert("Click to the box to get the no of days");
            document.getElementById('no_of_days').focus();
            return false;
            //errors[errors.length] = "Enter valid mobileno ";
        }
        else if (!(rc)) {
            alert("Select the room type");
            document.getElementById('roomtype').focus();
            return false;
            //errors[errors.length] = "Enter valid mobileno ";
        }
        else if (!(rpd)) {
            alert("Enter the Rate Per Day");
            document.getElementById('rp_day').focus();
            return false;
            //errors[errors.length] = "Enter valid mobileno ";
        }
        else if (!(rpb)) {
            alert("Enter the Rate Per Bed");
            document.getElementById('extrarate').focus();
            return false;
            //errors[errors.length] = "Enter valid mobileno ";
        }
        else if (!(tamt)) {
            alert("Click on the box to get the total amount");
            document.getElementById('totalamount').focus();
            return false;
            //errors[errors.length] = "Enter valid mobileno ";
        }
        else if (!(advamt)) {
            alert("Enter the advance amount");
            document.getElementById('advance_amount').focus();
            return false;
            //errors[errors.length] = "Enter valid mobileno ";
        }

    }

</script>
```

[check the jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ranjith12688/aojhh7eo/6)

once confirm radio button is clicked all disable elements are shown up...

Comment: Because you are using IF ELSE so if one condition will be True it will not check others use only IF for everything

Comment: its not necessary to accept all the form datas since i have two radio buttons......1.agent 2.direct.......if agent is clicked then form displays two more elements which is by default hidden...I dont know in this case is it possible to use if statement for everything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your form is doing

```
<form onsubmit="return validate(this)"
```

1. Fix the elses. There is no need for most of the else's and particularly the first one in your code will stop the rest of the validation if the agent is checked. I have added some code to handle the validation of either agent selected or typed - when it gets that big, a separate function would be better
2. change the || to && here> `if(!(book_by && bkother)) {`
3. rename AND change the ID of the second bookby field at the end of the form
4. remove the space from phone1 OR use trim to get rid of spaces before testing

---

```js
function validate(form1) {
  var....
  var....
  var....

  if(agent1.checked) {
    if (book_by == "") {
      alert('Choose a valid agent');
      document.getElementById('bookby').focus();
      return false;
    } else {
      if (bkother == "") {
        alert('Type an agent name');
        document.getElementById('bookbyother').focus();
        return false;
      }
      if (agntphn == "") {
        alert('Enter the agent phone number');
        document.getElementById('phone1').focus();
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  if (gstnam == "") {
    alert("Enter a valid Name ");
    document.getElementById('guest_name').focus();
    return false;
    //errors[errors.length] = "Enter valid Name ";
  }
  if (!ck_Mobileno.test(gstphn)) {
    alert("Enter a valid Mobile Number with 10 digits");
    document.getElementById('guest_no').focus();
    return false;
    //errors[errors.length] = "Enter valid mobileno ";
  }
  if ((adlts == "") && (children == "") && (infants == "")) {
    alert("Enter a valid No of persons");
    document.getElementById('no_adults').focus();
    return false;
    //errors[errors.length] = "Enter valid mobileno ";
  }
  if (!(check_in)) {
    alert("Enter a valid Checkin Date");
    document.getElementById('checkin').focus();
    return false;
    //errors[errors.length] = "Enter valid mobileno ";
  }
  if (!(check_out)) {
    alert("Enter a valid  check_out date");
    document.getElementById('checkout').focus();
    return false;
    //errors[errors.length] = "Enter valid mobileno ";
  }
  if (!(nfd1)) {
    alert("Click to the box to get the no of days");
    document.getElementById('no_of_days').focus();
    return false;
    //errors[errors.length] = "Enter valid mobileno ";
  }
  if (!(rc)) {
    alert("Select the room type");
    document.getElementById('roomtype').focus();
    return false;
    //errors[errors.length] = "Enter valid mobileno ";
  }
  if (!(rpd)) {
    alert("Enter the Rate Per Day");
    document.getElementById('rp_day').focus();
    return false;
    //errors[errors.length] = "Enter valid mobileno ";
  }
  if (!(rpb)) {
    alert("Enter the Rate Per Bed");
    document.getElementById('extrarate').focus();
    return false;
    //errors[errors.length] = "Enter valid mobileno ";
  }
  if (!(tamt)) {
    alert("Click on the box to get the total amount");
    document.getElementById('totalamount').focus();
    return false;
    //errors[errors.length] = "Enter valid mobileno ";
  }
  if (!(advamt)) {
    alert("Enter the advance amount");
    document.getElementById('advance_amount').focus();
    return false;
    //errors[errors.length] = "Enter valid mobileno ";
  }
  return true; // allow submission
}
```

Comment: no its not working the control goes  only to  the first alert message even the value  is entered

Comment: Then there is another error. Please check the console and post a jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ranjith12688/aojhh7eo/6/   if direct radio button is clicked then all the disabled elements are enabled its not working in fiddle but it works in my form...i dont know why??...Other than that this is how the functionality of the form looks like

Comment: sorry its not direct radio button its confirm radio button to show up all disabled elements...

Comment: I do not understand. 1) why did you choose jQuery in the jsfiddle - there is no jquery, 2) why onload? it just has to be head: - http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/60fvojxu/

Comment: i thought some times the disabled actions are done with the help of jquery but its not working...

Comment: You need to change         `if ((book_by == "" || bkother == ""))`
          
 to         `if ((book_by == "" && bkother == ""))`

Comment: I tried by giving (book_by == "" && bkother == "") but the second validation of agntphn=="" not working its going to the next validation part of guestname.

Comment: you ALSO need to NOT have TWO bookby fields, one agent and one not agent:  `<input type="text" id="bookby" name="bookby" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['admin'];?>" class="form-control" disabled>
<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>`

Comment: You had a space in the value `<input type="text" id="phone1" name="phone1" class="form-control" value="****">`

Comment: i dont know how to put positive for the commment....so oly i checked the above ans...

Answer (score 0):

You are using `if (condition) {} else if (condition) {}`.  The first condition that matches is all that will be executed.

If you want all tests to be executed, then remove the `else`.

```
    if ((agent1.checked == true))
    {
        if(!(book_by || bkother))
        {
            alert('Choose the valid agent');
            return false;
        }
        else if(agntphn =="")
        {
            alert('Enter the agent phone number')
            return false;
        }
    }

    // == > don't use else if here, just a plain if
    if (gstnam=="") {
        alert("Enter a valid Name ");
        document.getElementById('guest_name').focus();
        return false;
    }

    // ... continuing on for the rest of your if statements
```

If, based on the data, you want only some of the tests to be executed, then you will have to break the code into blocks and use the right `if` tests to determine which code executes for which conditions.  But, the way you had it would only execute the first condition that matched and **none** of the others.

Comment: i have 2 radio buttons based on that the form validation has to be executed....If agent radio button is selected, the form show two more elements which is by default hidden.....and if agent radio button is clicked not all values shown up there are necessary...If diirect radio button is clicked then all values are checked except the hidden elements...

Comment: @RanjithR - so you will have to code that logic into your `if` statements so you only check the things you should check based on the state of the page.  You haven't specified near enough detail for anyone to offer any coding details on how that would be coded.